# Get which Host/I.P ES TransportClient is connected to

Tags: elasticsearch

Using E.S 1.5.2

Is their a way to get the I.P address/hostname of the node the Transport client connected to?

Classses used...

```
TransportClient
SearchSourceBuilder
SearchRequestBuilder
SearchResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

SearchResponse has remoteAddress(). That did the trick for me.